# Having to double press a tact switch?

Tags: arduino, switches, integrated-circuit

I have created a simple circuit consisting of a 4017 ic, a tact switch, and arduino. The arduino is just for debouncing purposes. For some reason i have to double press the switch for the input to go through.

```
int button = 2;
int CLK = 3;

volatile boolean lastbutton = LOW;
volatile boolean currentbutton = LOW;
volatile boolean CLKlvl = LOW;

void setup() {
  pinMode(button, INPUT);
  pinMode(CLK, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
  currentbutton = debounce(lastbutton);
  if (lastbutton == LOW && currentbutton == HIGH){
    CLKlvl = !CLKlvl;
  }
  lastbutton = currentbutton;

  digitalWrite(CLK, CLKlvl);

}

 boolean debounce(boolean last){
 boolean current = digitalRead(button);
 if (last != current){
   delay(5);
   current = digitalRead(button);
 }
 return current ; 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Apparently you have what's known as a *"bug"* in your code.

Comment: Your `debounce` is not really debouncing.

Comment: Shouldn't your lastbutton = currentbutton; be insde the if statement.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I don't think so. The OP is trying to detect low-to-high transitions, if I understand it right.

Comment: Well then he has to detect it twice to get input to transition.  One L to H to get CLKlvl high.  A second time to get CLKlvl low.  Repeat, which does explain the behavior.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I am not sure what is the intended behavior, but *assuming* the debouncing function is working, each switch press (low to high transition) should toggle the output to an opposite state. Update: Actually it is what you said, sorry.

Comment: Does it do this every time? I suggest trying to attach an interrupt to the switch. It is much more accurate than polling.

Answer (score 1):

You flip the clock output on every LOW to HIGH transition (which occurs once per press), which means to get an active (rising on the 4017) clock edge you have to press it twice.

You could get rid of that conditional statement- just output currentbutton to the clock after the debounce and it should work.